# Changing the property values of an object in an array using another property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array as below. What I'd like to implement is a function that takes the node's ID, x and y as its inputs and make changes accordingly in the array.

```
var nodes = [{ID:"101", x:100, y:200}
             ,{ID:"102", x:200, y:200}
             ,{ID:"103", x:300, y:300}
             ,{ID:"104", x:200, y:300}];
```

For example, `function (102,200,300);` will update the x and y of the second object in the array as `{ID:"102", x:200, y:300}`.

What I have done is this:

```
function update(id,x,y){
    for (var i=0 in nodes){
        if (nodes[i].ID==id){
            nodes[i].x = x;
            nodes[i].y = y;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know other methods apart from using for loop and if condition to check and update. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you're expecting here. If you have an array of nonspecific elements you're going to end up looping one way or another, unless the objects are always in the same order and can be accessed by their index. How are their IDs generated / how are they pushed onto the array?

If you want to avoid the loop, you should just store your objects in an object instead, and make their IDs the key-property.

```
var nodes = {
    '101': {ID: '101', x:100, y:200},
    '102': {ID: '102', x:200, y:200},
    '103': {ID: '103', x:300, y:300},
    '104': {ID: '104', x:200, y:300}
};
```

Then you can access them directly.

```
function setv(id, x, y) {
    if (nodes.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        nodes[id].x = x;
        nodes[id].y = y;
    }
}
```

Also, you should avoid using [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on arrays - use a regular `for` loop, or [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Simple way to loop on an object, and check its properties and values:

```
function logObj(obj) {
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            console.log(p, obj[p]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's an array like I've stated, I can use `for(var i =0;i<nodes.length;i++)` to display all the objects in the array. If I change the array into objects as per your suggestion, how will my for loop look like(to display all the objects inside)? @Oka

Comment: I've added a small example of  that to the answer.